# SQL statement to get the date next 2 days from now

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to get the data which the date is next 2 days from today below are my sql statement, i am using mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM guest g inner join reservation r on g.nric = r.guestNric 
WHERE arrivalDate = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +2 DAY)
```

My problem now is if i am using = becuase my arrivalDate format is 'yyyy-MM-dd' then the Date_Add format is come with timestamp so it wont be equals any idea how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: He said mysql in the question text, just didn't tag it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM guest g inner join reservation r on g.nric = r.guestNric 
WHERE arrivalDate = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +2 DAY))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `NOW()`with `CURTIME()`. The type return value of DATE_ADD() corresponds to the type of the first parameter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replied i got incorrect datetime value error message