# MySQL query to get data in date range specified in days count

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `questions`. In that table there is a field call `question_date`. Field is **datetime**.

I want to check all the question those are asked between 5-7 days only.

I have tried below query but I am getting blank output. No records was there.

```
SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `question_date` < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND question_date >= NOW()

SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `question_date` = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY))
```

I have checked the below questions:

[mysql query to get birthdays for next 10 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226062/mysql-query-to-get-birthdays-for-next-10-days)

[SQL statement to get the date next 2 days from now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098900/sql-statement-to-get-the-date-next-2-days-from-now)

Comment: Can you share sample data and expected response

Comment: You need exactly 5 days or between 5 and 7?

Comment: between 5 and 7 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM `questions` 
WHERE `question_date` < date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND question_date >= date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up. Let me try.

Comment: if you can share the sample data and expected response. I can help you with proper ans.

Answer (score -1):

You can try same below:
select * from demo where DAT between DATE_SUB('2017-02-04', INTERVAL 2 DAY) and '2017-02-04'